# onbeforeunload issue in IE browser

Tags: jquery

I am using below code for leaving the current page. 
It works fine in chrome and mozilla, but it is calling for every anchor tags in IE 10 browser.
What can I do to prevent calling this in IE 10 browser?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function()
{   
   return  "";
};
```

Comment: this seems to be a reasonable question, wonder why it was voted to be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is default behavior of IE, you need to remove onbeforeunload event from anchor tag while you are hovering over it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //store onbeforeunload for later use
    $(window).data('beforeunload',window.onbeforeunload);  

      //remove||re-assign onbeforeunload on hover 
    $('a')
      .hover( 
             function(){window.onbeforeunload=null;},
             function(){window.onbeforeunload=$(window).data('beforeunload');}
            );


});
```

Or you need to 'return false' onClick event of each anchor tag:

```
<a onclick="someFunction(); return false;" href="lnk" >my link</a>
```

Comment: i used the above code still onclick of anchor tag again will caliing the onbefore unload

Comment: still not working some one can give me the exact solution with my above code

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
var e = e || window.event;

// For IE and Firefox
if (e) {
    e.returnValue = '';
}

// For Chrome and Safari
return '';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
   function closeIt()
   {
      return "Any string value here forces a dialog box to \n" + 
     "appear before closing the window.";
    }
  window.onbeforeunload = closeIt;
</script>
</head>
```